# SSH over incoming call from faxmodem possible?

Tags: linux, ssh, modem

I have a flaky broadband internet connection, and, seperated from that, a classic analog landline. Furthermore, I have a raspberry pi and a usb 56k-faxmodem.

When I am not at home and can't reach my Pi over the internet, I'd like to call it over landline, and maybe doing some basic things like rebooting my router. Of course, I'd like to do that over a secure connection.

Is it possible to configure the Pi to accept incoming calls and relay the conversation to openssh-server?

Comment: This is classic PPP or SLIP; do you have a modem at the sending end?

Comment: @Stephen Yes, I have.

Comment: Would work if it was really a landline, but it's no longer feasible here in Germany, too much voip, classic landlines are a thing of the past. (It might look like a landline to your house but it's not really all of the way, signal gets compressed/lost in transmission). And they cheat to make the fax protocol work but a regular modem - not so much.

Comment: @frostschutz My nickname might suggest that, but this is not for a setup in germany.

Comment: What exactly do you (want to) use on the other end of the modem connection? Instead of using SSH over PPP or SLIP you could use a serial terminal with `mgetty` or some other modem-capable `getty` variant. This would require a simple terminal program on the other end.

Comment: @Bodo In the end, I'd like to have a (secure) terminal connection on both ends.

Comment: Analogue modems using 56K adaptive protocols are pretty secure.

Comment: @roaima Can you elaborate on that? What protocols are (or can be) in use between modems?

Comment: @LangerJan you say you're using a 56K modem. Assuming the other side is also using 56K then they will use a protocol that adapts dynamically to the available frequency range on the line. It's been a _very_ long time since I last needed to know all this so I don't have the details to hand, but basically since the two sides keep adapting it's hard for a passive listener to keep in step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `getty` implementations which support this directly, for example [Mgetty](http://mgetty.greenie.net/) (which should be available in your distribution). This will handle the modem on the server side, waiting for calls, answering them, and presenting a login prompt on data calls. On the calling side, you’d use something like [Minicom](https://salsa.debian.org/minicom-team/minicom) to dial your phone and connect to the target system.

That should be sufficient to give you the access you’re after. It won’t be using SSH though.

Once you have established a connection, you can layer other protocols on top of it. Mgetty can be configured to detect PAP / CHAP negotiation attempts, and automatically start a PPP connection over the serial link; that will give you point-to-point IP, so you can run SSH or any other IP tool. You can also start a PPP server manually.

Mgetty can also be configured to handle faxes and voice calls, all on the same line, so you can set up an answering machine alongside your data connection. It can also handle callbacks (*e.g.* if your calls are cheaper from the Pi, or if you want to verify the caller).